# Disable Object's Camera Rendering for one Render Layer only

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-layers, visibility

I have a scene with two objects, one glowing and other semi-glossy. I want to composite the render, so I created render layers, one for glowing object and one for glossy one. Then, I immediately notice that **glowing object now does not appear in reflection** of another one. I googled and figured out that you can make object only be reflected using visibility tab (by unchecking the **camera ray visibility** and keeping all others as is) in object settings. But the thing is, these settings seem to be **global for all render layers**, which hides the object on all layers, even on one where this object supposed to be visible.

Is there any way to make this setting per layer and not global? Or maybe there's other, more appropriate way to do such thing?

I'm using cycles and blender version 3.0.1

**Edit**: I worked around this problem by creating linked duplicate of the glowing object and moving it to separate collection, and then changing its visibility separately from the original one. But this is too dirty for my taste, would be nice if there was some better way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way, you can click on filter icon on the top of the **Outliner Editor** (scene hierarchy) and enable **Indirect only**. This will show new icon on the right of collections (next to hide in render icon), which enables you to make a collection to **only be rendered in indirect way** (e.g. reflections)